# How to click an element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So I have this element in HTML...

`<a href="#" onclick="on_catolog(2);"><span style="font-size:11pt">Security</span></a>`

... and I want to click it using Selenium in python. How can I do it? (Maybe I can identify it using onclick, but how?)

Also, here is what I've tried:

```
security = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick=\"on_catolog(2);\"]")
security.click()
```

Comment: Show how you tried. Share code

Comment: there ya go @JaSON

Answer (score 1):

You used wrong tag name in your XPath `"//button[@onclick=\"on_catolog(2);\"]"`. It's not a button, but anchor tag. Try

```
"//a[@onclick='on_catolog(2);']"
```

Or click by link text:

```
security = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Security")
security.click()
```

Comment: I get this error with both methods `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @chronovirus what if to put `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` before searching for element?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Security** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick^='on_catolog'] > span[style='font-size:11pt']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'on_catolog')]/span[text()='Security']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick^='on_catolog'] > span[style='font-size:11pt']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'on_catolog')]/span[text()='Security']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```